# Get height of cell in collection view custom layout based on image height

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am loading an image from the url in a collection view with the follwoing custom layout https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2 and loading the images in collection view cells using kingfisher as follows

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DbatCollectionViewCell",
                                                  for: indexPath) as! DbatCollectionViewCell

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    let debate = debatesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let debateDetails = debate.value(forKey: "debate") as! Debate
    cell.dbatName?.text = debateDetails.title
    if let debateImageUrl = URL(string: debateDetails.image!) {
        cell.dbatImage.kf.setImage(with: debateImageUrl as Resource)
    }

    return cell
  }
```

In that tutorial, the height of the cell is provided by image height, but I want to give the image size based on the ratio of the image whether it is portrait or landscape image. For that I have to find the height of the image in

```
extension FavouriteCollectionViewController : DbatterLayoutDelegate {

// 1. Returns the photo height
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let heights = [125,150, 175,200,225,250]
    let number = heights[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(heights.count)))]

    return CGFloat(number)
}
}
```

Please advise on how to do this

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Anushk yes I had solved it. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I had uploaded the image size including height and width during uploading the image and calculated the image height as follow

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let debate = debatesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let debateDetails = debate.value(forKey: "debate") as! Debate

    if debateDetails.image_size != nil {
        let imageDictionary = debateDetails.image_size

        let width = CGFloat((imageDictionary?.value(forKey: "width") as! NSString).floatValue)
        let height = CGFloat((imageDictionary?.value(forKey: "height") as! NSString).floatValue)

        let cellWidth = collectionView.contentSize.width / 2
        let imageheight = cellWidth * height / width

        return imageheight
    }

    return 200
}
```